# Cannot compile c++ on MacOs

Tags: clang

trying to learn to code in C++ (or C). I would like to use marplot++ to plot from C++.

I have the simple code (copied from the site) that I would like to compile. It has the following two includes:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <matplot/matplot.h>
```

I installed `brew` and `marplot.h` is in the directory /opt/homebrew/Cellar....(see below).

The corresponding library seems to be (it exists, I checked)
"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/lib/libmatplot.dylb"

I try to compile with:

```
clang  -std=c++20  -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/include"  -L"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/lib/" -llibmatplot.dylib -o ExercisePython ExercisePython.cpp
```

The output ends with:

```
clang  -std=c++20  -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/include"  -L"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/lib/" -llibmatplot.dylib -o ExercisePython ExercisePython.cpp
ld: library 'libmatplot.dylib' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ExercisePython] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
I **don't want to use Xcode** because I want to learn the command line and the various concepts (and anyway I failed also with Xcode).

PS: MacOs Sonoma 14
command line tools installed,
brew installed.

I tried several permutations of the -l flag, with and without .dylib.

Comment: Did you try -lmatplot ?

Comment: Yes, just now, and a much longer list of errors comes up.
clang  -std=c++20  -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/include"  -L"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/lib/" -lmatplot -o ExercisePython ExercisePython.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::length_error::length_error[abi:ue170006](char const*) in 
[........]
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ExercisePython] Error 1

Comment: Can you post some of them?

Comment: I imagine the problem is that there is no library named matplot.

Here is the ls of the directory ..../lib
cmake/                  libmatplot.1.2.0.dylib*  libmatplot.dylib@

Comment: I also tried -llibmatplot.1.2.0 with and without dylib

Comment: No, in fact you are not linking the shared libraries used by libmatplot.dylib. You can check the libraries used by it with `otool -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.2.1/lib/libmatplot.dylib`
Edit: sorry about autocorrect, fixed the name of the command line tool

Comment: Likely some of the errors will disappear if you invoke the C++ compiler with `clang++` instead of `clang`.

Comment: Don't have "tool"  and "brew install tool" can't find it either. Clang++ same errors

Comment: It's actually `otool`, I just got autocorrected

Comment: Here is output `libmatplot.dylib:
 /opt/homebrew/opt/matplotplusplus/lib/libmatplot.1.2.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1.2.0)
[...]
 /opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/lib/libfftw3l_omp.3.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.10.0)
 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.157.0)`

Comment: You likely need to add `-lfftw3l_omp` to Clang++’s command line options. Not `-lc++`, though, if you use `clang++`.

Comment: can't find that too.

Comment: So you need to add its library path, too, i.e. `-L/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/lib`

Comment: Also IIRC the option order is significant, so the library path must be specified first if you want the compiler driver to find the library that you specify with `-l`